# jQuery AJAX reloading data into a DOM or refreshing the DOM with new data

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a piece of code using jQuery to load content from an internal webpage onto a new page DOM after the user has selected a button from another page. The problem I got is no matter what option button I click the same result shows in the DOM. I was told to change the Var to .live but it hasn't made any difference. I cant really explain it more apart from some one looking at my code. What is the best way to deal with this?

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery Mobile Web App</title>
<link href="../jquery.mobile.theme-1.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="../jquery.mobile.structure-1.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="../jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page" id="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page One</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">   
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li><a href="#options">Options</a></li>
            <li><a href="#results">results</a></li>
        </ul>       
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="options">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Options</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">   
        <div id="page-wrap">
            <div id="header">
                <h1>Call a webpage in a DOM</h1>
            </div>

            <div id="load-div" class="functions">
                <span>Value 1</span>
                <input type="submit" value="300GB" id="load" />

<div id="load-div" class="functions">
                <span>Value 2</span>
                <input type="submit" value="500Gb" id="load2" />
            </div>
            <a href="#results">results</a>      

        </div>  
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div>
</div>
</div>






<div data-role="page" id="results">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Results</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">

                    <div id="result"  class="functions">

</div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajaxSetup ({
        cache: false
    });
    var ajax_load = "<img class='loading' src='img/load.gif' alt='loading...' />";
//  load() functions
    var loadUrl = "load.html";
    $("#load").live("click",function(){
        $("#result").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl);
    });

</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajaxSetup ({
        cache: false
    });
    var ajax_load = "<img class='loading' src='img/load.gif' alt='loading...' />";
//  load() functions
    var loadUrl = "load2.html";
    $("#load_2").live("click",function(){
        $("#result").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl);
    });

</script>

<a href="#options">Options</a>  
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you overwrite every script you have here. Don't use `loadUrl`.

**For `#load`:**

```
$("#load").live("click",function(){
    $('#result').html(ajax_load).load('load.html');
});
```

**And for `#load2`:**

```
$("#load_2").live("click",function(){
    $("#result").html(ajax_load).load(`load2.html`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Separate script tags are not independent. The code in one can interact with the code in another.

You have declared var ajax_load and loadUrl in both blocks. The ones in the second block overwrite those in the first. Either give them different names, or eliminate them and put the string values directly in your function.